# Несколько цветов для заполнения stroke по окружности

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, градиент

Я хочу создать радугу по окружности, как на рисунке ниже.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но как мне нарисовать изогнутый и многоцветный градиент?

Вот мой текущий код:

```html
<svg width="500" height="500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<defs>
<linearGradient id="test">
<stop offset="0%" stop-color="#f00"/>
<stop offset="100%" stop-color="#0ff"/>
</linearGradient>

</defs>

<circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="none" stroke="url(#test)" stroke-width="6"/>

</svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [svg multiple color on circle stroke](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18206361/7394871)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18206361/svg-multiple-color-on-circle-stroke/18210763#18210763

Comment: я тоже думал над  [этим](/a/734502/268783)... есть еще D3JS по сути это тоже самое, ничего нового, но более изящно

Comment: @UModeL У меня к Вам большая просьба - восстановите пожалуйста свой удаленный ответ. Ответ был хорошо оценен +4 Значит он был полезен людям, в том числе и мне понравился ваш ответ. .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Такое возможно при помощи [полифилла](http://leaverou.github.io/conic-gradient/) `conic-gradient` Лии Веру.

```css
.circle {
  background: conic-gradient(#f00, #ff00bd, #0020ff, #00f3ff, #00ff08, #fff700, #f00);
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

.circle:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  width: calc(100% - 40px);
  height: calc(100% - 40px);
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>

<script src="https://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://leaverou.github.io/conic-gradient/conic-gradient.js"></script>
```

Comment: Взять png, превратить в base64, положить его в svg и ещё раз превратить в base64. Странная схема... А ещё точность ыентра вызывает некоторые сомнения.

Comment: @Qwertiy даже больше - взять канвас, нарисовать на нем картинку, превратить в пнг и дальше уже всё остальное. Видимо, на канве конический градиент из линий рисовать всё-таки быстрее, чем делать кучу линий сразу в свг.

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko, я имел в виду, что png в base64 вроде уже должно быть можно поместить в background. Непонятно, зачем нужен промежуточный svg.

Comment: @Qwertiy почему по умолчанию Лия сделала такой вывод мне и самому не понятно. но вдруг понадобится — этот скрипт можно использовать не только как полифилл, у него есть АПИ, которое может вернуть png/base64 сразу.

Answer (score 7):

Такой подход не будет работать. SVG не имеет конических градиентов. Чтобы имитировать эффект, вам нужно было бы подделать его большим количеством маленьких отрезков. Или применить какую-то другую, подобную технику.

### Update:

Вот пример. Я аппроксимирую `360deg` оттенками на шести отрезках, созданными  `path's`.  Каждый `path` содержит дугу, которая покрывает 60 градусов окружности.  Я использую `linear gradient` для интерполяции цвета от начала до конца каждого пути.

Это не идеально (вы можете увидеть некоторые разрывы, где цвета встречаются), но это не заметит большинство людей. Вы можете увеличить точность, используя более шести сегментов.

```html
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="220" height="220" viewBox="-10 -10 220 220">
      <defs>
        <linearGradient id="redyel" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1" y2="1">
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#ff0000"/>   
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#ffff00"/>   
        </linearGradient>
        <linearGradient id="yelgre" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="1">
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#ffff00"/>   
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#00ff00"/>   
        </linearGradient>
        <linearGradient id="grecya" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" x1="1" y1="0" x2="0" y2="1">
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#00ff00"/>   
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#00ffff"/>   
        </linearGradient>
        <linearGradient id="cyablu" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" x1="1" y1="1" x2="0" y2="0">
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#00ffff"/>   
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#0000ff"/>   
        </linearGradient>
        <linearGradient id="blumag" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" x1="0" y1="1" x2="0" y2="0">
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#0000ff"/>   
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#ff00ff"/>   
        </linearGradient>
        <linearGradient id="magred" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" x1="0" y1="1" x2="1" y2="0">
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#ff00ff"/>   
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#ff0000"/>   
        </linearGradient>
      </defs>
    
      <g fill="none" stroke-width="15" transform="translate(100,100)">
        <path d="M 0,-100 A 100,100 0 0,1 86.6,-50" stroke="url(#redyel)"/>
        <path d="M 86.6,-50 A 100,100 0 0,1 86.6,50" stroke="url(#yelgre)"/>
        <path d="M 86.6,50 A 100,100 0 0,1 0,100" stroke="url(#grecya)"/>
        <path d="M 0,100 A 100,100 0 0,1 -86.6,50" stroke="url(#cyablu)"/>
        <path d="M -86.6,50 A 100,100 0 0,1 -86.6,-50" stroke="url(#blumag)"/>
        <path d="M -86.6,-50 A 100,100 0 0,1 0,-100" stroke="url(#magred)"/>
      </g>
    </svg>
```

Пример на [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Weytu/)

### Update 2:

Для вариантов, с шестью и более сегментами, есть решение на `javascript`, которое будет создавать круг с любым количеством сегментов.

В примере ниже используется 12 сегментов.

```js
function makeColourWheel(numSegments)
{
    if (numSegments <= 0)
        numSegments = 12;
    if (numSegments > 360)
        numSegments = 360;

    var  svgns = xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
    var  svg = document.getElementById("colourwheel");
    var  defs = svg.getElementById("defs");
    var  paths = svg.getElementById("paths");

    var  radius = 100;
    var  stepAngle = 2 * Math.PI / numSegments;

    var  lastX = 0;
    var  lastY = -radius;
    var  lastAngle = 0;
    
    for (var i=1; i<=numSegments; i++)
    {
        var  angle = i * stepAngle;

        // Рассчитайте эту конечную точку дуги
        var x = radius * Math.sin(angle);
        var y = -radius * Math.cos(angle);
        // Создайте элемент пути
        var arc = document.createElementNS(svgns, "path");
        arc.setAttribute("d", "M " + lastX.toFixed(3) + "," + lastY.toFixed(3)
                              + " A 100,100 0 0,1 " + x.toFixed(3) + "," + y.toFixed(3));
        arc.setAttribute("stroke", "url(#wheelseg" + i + ")");
        // Добавьте его в наш SVG
        paths.appendChild(arc);
        
        // Создайте градиент для этого сегмента
        var grad = document.createElementNS(svgns, "linearGradient");
        grad.setAttribute("id", "wheelseg"+i);
        grad.setAttribute("gradientUnits", "userSpaceOnUse");
        grad.setAttribute("x1", lastX.toFixed(3));
        grad.setAttribute("y1", lastY.toFixed(3));
        grad.setAttribute("x2", x.toFixed(3));
        grad.setAttribute("y2", y.toFixed(3));
        // Сделайте stop 0% для этого градиента
        var stop = document.createElementNS(svgns, "stop");
        stop.setAttribute("offset", "0%");
        hue = Math.round(lastAngle * 360 / Math.PI / 2);
        stop.setAttribute("stop-color", "hsl(" + hue + ",100%,50%)");
        grad.appendChild(stop);
        //Сделайте 100% stop для этого градиента
        stop = document.createElementNS(svgns, "stop");
        stop.setAttribute("offset", "100%");
        hue = Math.round(angle * 360 / Math.PI / 2);
        stop.setAttribute("stop-color", "hsl(" + hue + ",100%,50%)");
        grad.appendChild(stop);
        // Добавьте градиент к SVG
        defs.appendChild(grad);

        // Обновите последние x/y
        lastX = x;
        lastY = y;
        lastAngle = angle;
    }
}


makeColourWheel(60);
```

```html
<svg id="colourwheel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="-10 -10 220 220">
  <defs id="defs">
  </defs>

  <g id="paths" fill="none" stroke-width="15" transform="translate(100,100)">
  </g>
</svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод ответа [svg multiple color on circle stroke](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18210763/7394871) от участника  [@Paul LeBeau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1292848/paul-lebeau).</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Добавлю перевод моего ответа на похожий вопрос в английской версии: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58399254/1566316 с дополнением.

Можно использовать преобразование центральной проекции (перспективы) над прямоугольниками с линейным градиентом, сжав их в треугольники по одной стороне с помощью transform:matrix3d или rotate3d и perspective в css.

Если четвёртый параметр matrix3d не равен нулю, он задаёт обратное (1/x) значение кординаты точки схода перспективы на оси х линии горизонта. Тринадцатый параметр смещает прямоугольник по горизонтали. Хотя и допустимо использовать calc в матрице, она не работает с единицами измерения, поэтому при масштабировании работа matrix3d сбивается и использовтать её получается только в svg и только в Firefox, так как в svg в Chromium не поддерживаются параметры, ответсвенные за перспективу (4, 8). Однако в последнем уже есть conic-gradient, хотя его нельзя применить к любому элементу svg, а только к foreignObject. Как работает свойство tranform-origin в svg мне так и не удалось разобраться, поэтому элементы матрицы частично подобраны наугад.

SVG версия цветового круга.

```html
<svg version="2" viewBox="-207 -207 414 414" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <defs>
  <radialGradient id="gWt">
   <stop style="stop-color:#fff" offset="0"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:#fff0" offset="1"/>
  </radialGradient>
  <!-- part for firefox: using central projection of 3 rectangles -->
  <linearGradient id="gYM" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="100%">
   <stop style="stop-color:#ef08" offset="0"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:#ff0" offset=".005"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:#fc0" offset=".1827"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:#f90" offset=".2924"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:#f60" offset=".3728"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:#f00" offset=".5"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:#f06" offset=".6272"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:#f09" offset=".7076"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:#f0c" offset=".8173"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:#f0f" offset=".995"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:#e0f8" offset="1"/>
  </linearGradient>
  <linearGradient id="gCY" href="#gYM">
   <stop style="stop-color:#0ef8" offset="0"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:#0ff" offset=".005"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:#0fc" offset=".1827"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:#0f9" offset=".2924"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:#0f6" offset=".3728"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:#0f0" offset=".5"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:#6f0" offset=".6272"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:#9f0" offset=".7076"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:#cf0" offset=".8173"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:#ff0" offset=".995"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:#fe08" offset="1"/>
  </linearGradient>
  <linearGradient id="gMC" href="#gYM">
   <stop style="stop-color:#f0e8" offset="0"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:#f0f" offset=".005"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:#c0f" offset=".1827"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:#90f" offset=".2924"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:#60f" offset=".3728"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:#00f" offset=".5"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:#06f" offset=".6272"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:#09f" offset=".7076"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:#0cf" offset=".8173"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:#0ff" offset=".995"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:#0fe8" offset="1"/>
  </linearGradient>
  <rect id="r" width="2000" height="700" style="transform:matrix3d(
      -29,0,0,100,
      0,1,0,0,
      0,0,1,0,
      200,-350,1,1
    ); mix-blend-mode:lighten"/>
 </defs>
 <clipPath id="cc">
  <circle r="200" id="c"/>
 </clipPath>
 <circle r="199" fill="#000"/>
 <g clip-path="url(#cc)" id="m">
  <use href="#r" fill="url(#gCY)" transform="rotate(-120)"/>
  <use href="#r" fill="url(#gYM)"/>
  <use href="#r" fill="url(#gMC)" transform="rotate(120)"/>
  <!-- for Chrome use conic gradient (does not work with any svg object but with foreign)
   Firefox ignores this object due to unknown keyword in style -->
 <foreignObject width="400" height="400" x="-200" y="-200" style="background:conic-gradient(from 90deg,
   #f00,#f0f,#00f,#0ff,#0f0,#ff0,#f00);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: auto;"/>
 </g>
 <g>
  <!-- Points for visual test -->
  <circle cx="-200" r="6" fill="#0ff"/>
  <circle cx="-195.6" cy="-41.6" r="6" fill="#0fc"/>
  <circle cx="-182.7" cy="-81.3" r="6" fill="#0f9"/>
  <circle cx="-161.8" cy="-117.6" r="6" fill="#0f6"/>
  <circle cx="-133.8" cy="-148.6" r="6" fill="#0f3"/>
  <circle cx="-100" cy="-173.2" r="6" fill="#0f0"/>
  <circle cx="-61.8" cy="-190.2" r="6" fill="#3f0"/>
  <circle cx="-20.9" cy="-198.9" r="6" fill="#6f0"/>
  <circle cx="20.9" cy="-198.9" r="6" fill="#9f0"/>
  <circle cx="61.8" cy="-190.2" r="6" fill="#cf0"/>
  <circle cx="100" cy="-173.2" r="6" fill="#ff0"/>
  <circle cx="133.8" cy="-148.6" r="6" fill="#fc0"/>
  <circle cx="161.8" cy="-117.6" r="6" fill="#f90"/>
  <circle cx="182.7" cy="-81.3" r="6" fill="#f60"/>
  <circle cx="195.6" cy="-41.6" r="6" fill="#f30"/>
  <circle cx="200" r="6" fill="#f00"/>
  <circle cx="-195.6" cy="41.6" r="6" fill="#0cf"/>
  <circle cx="-182.7" cy="81.3" r="6" fill="#09f"/>
  <circle cx="-161.8" cy="117.6" r="6" fill="#06f"/>
  <circle cx="-133.8" cy="148.6" r="6" fill="#03f"/>
  <circle cx="-100" cy="173.2" r="6" fill="#00f"/>
  <circle cx="-61.8" cy="190.2" r="6" fill="#30f"/>
  <circle cx="-20.9" cy="198.9" r="6" fill="#60f"/>
  <circle cx="20.9" cy="198.9" r="6" fill="#90f"/>
  <circle cx="61.8" cy="190.2" r="6" fill="#c0f"/>
  <circle cx="100" cy="173.2" r="6" fill="#f0f"/>
  <circle cx="133.8" cy="148.6" r="6" fill="#f0c"/>
  <circle cx="161.8" cy="117.6" r="6" fill="#f09"/>
  <circle cx="182.7" cy="81.3" r="6" fill="#f06"/>
  <circle cx="195.6" cy="41.6" r="6" fill="#f03"/>
 </g>
 <circle r="200" fill="url(#gWt)"/>
</svg>
```

Контрольные точки градиента получены по следующей формуле (из геометрии прямоугольного треугольника со сторонами 350х200):

```
0.5 ± tan(v/255.*pi/3)/350*100.
```

где v - значение изменяющегося цветового канала.

SVG версия кольца.

```html
<svg version="2" viewBox="-207 -207 414 414" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <defs>
  <radialGradient id="gWt">
   <stop style="stop-color:#fff" offset="0"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:#fff0" offset="1"/>
  </radialGradient>
  <!-- part for firefox: using central projection of 3 rectangles -->
  <linearGradient id="gYM" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="100%">
   <stop style="stop-color:#ef08" offset="0"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:#ff0" offset=".005"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:#fc0" offset=".1827"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:#f90" offset=".2924"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:#f60" offset=".3728"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:#f00" offset=".5"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:#f06" offset=".6272"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:#f09" offset=".7076"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:#f0c" offset=".8173"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:#f0f" offset=".995"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:#e0f8" offset="1"/>
  </linearGradient>
  <linearGradient id="gCY" href="#gYM">
   <stop style="stop-color:#0ef8" offset="0"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:#0ff" offset=".005"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:#0fc" offset=".1827"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:#0f9" offset=".2924"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:#0f6" offset=".3728"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:#0f0" offset=".5"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:#6f0" offset=".6272"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:#9f0" offset=".7076"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:#cf0" offset=".8173"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:#ff0" offset=".995"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:#fe08" offset="1"/>
  </linearGradient>
  <linearGradient id="gMC" href="#gYM">
   <stop style="stop-color:#f0e8" offset="0"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:#f0f" offset=".005"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:#c0f" offset=".1827"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:#90f" offset=".2924"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:#60f" offset=".3728"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:#00f" offset=".5"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:#06f" offset=".6272"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:#09f" offset=".7076"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:#0cf" offset=".8173"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:#0ff" offset=".995"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:#0fe8" offset="1"/>
  </linearGradient>
  <rect id="r" width="200" height="700" style="transform:matrix3d(
      -29,0,0,100,
      0,1,0,0,
      0,0,1,0,
      200,-350,1,1
    )"/>
 </defs>
 <clipPath id="cc">
  <path d="M200,0A200,200,0, 1,0,0,200 200,200,0,0,0,200,0zM100,0A100,100,0, 0,1,0,100 100,100,0, 1,1,100,0z"/>
 </clipPath>
 <!-- circle r="199" fill="#000"/ -->
 <g clip-path="url(#cc)" id="m">
  <use href="#r" fill="url(#gCY)" transform="rotate(-120)"/>
  <use href="#r" fill="url(#gYM)"/>
  <use href="#r" fill="url(#gMC)" transform="rotate(120)"/>
  <!-- for Chrome use conic gradient (does not work with any svg object but with foreign)
   Firefox ignores this object due to unknown keyword in style -->
 <foreignObject width="400" height="400" x="-200" y="-200" style="background:conic-gradient(from 90deg,
   #f00,#f0f,#00f,#0ff,#0f0,#ff0,#f00);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: auto;"/>
 </g>
</svg>
```

В HTML можно использовать transform:rotate3D. Расположив точку зрения очень близко к прямоугольнику можно получить почти треугольник.

```css
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.c{
   height:90vmin;
   width:90vmin;
   margin:5vmin;
   overflow: hidden;
   border-radius:50%;
   position:absolute;
}
.c>div{
   position:relative;
   height:180vmin;
   width:100vmin;
   perspective: 0.40vmin;
   top:-45vmin;
   left:-4.8vmin;
}
.c>div>div{
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   left:0;
   top:1%;
   height: 98%;
   transform-origin:99.98% 50%;
   position:relative;
   transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -80deg);
   border:black;
}
#YM>div{
   background:linear-gradient(#ef08,#ff0 0.5%,#fc0 18.27%,#f90 29.24%,#f60 37.28%,#f00 50%,#f06 62.72%,#f09 70.76%,#f0c 81.73%,#f0f 99.5%,#e0f8);
}
#MC{
   transform: rotateZ(120deg);
}
#CY{
   transform: rotateZ(-120deg);
}
#MC>div{
   background:linear-gradient(#f0e8,#f0f 0.5%,#c0f 18.27%,#90f 29.24%,#60f 37.28%,#00f 50%,#06f 62.72%,#09f 70.76%,#0cf 81.73%,#0ff 99.5%,#0fe8);
}
#CY>div{
   background:linear-gradient(#0ef8,#0ff 0.5%,#0fc 18.27%,#0f9 29.24%,#0f6 37.28%,#0f0 50%,#6f0 62.72%,#9f0 70.76%,#cf0 81.73%,#ff0 99.5%,#fe08);
}
```

```html
<div class="c"><div id="YM"><div></div></div></div>
<div class="c"><div id="MC"><div></div></div></div>
<div class="c"><div id="CY"><div></div></div></div>
```

Comment: Замечательный, полезный ответ! (+) Видимо  ваш основной браузер FF, поэтому не заметили, что последний пример не работает в Chrome/

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, работает, но только в развёрнутом виде, при уменьшении размера окна картинка уменьшается, а потом внезапно исчезает, - странный эффект.