# Как нарисовать разукрашенный круг на svg?

Tags: css, svg, frontend

Как на svg нарисовать такой круг, чтоб его закрашенность оранжевым цветом можно было легко менять от 0 до 100% ? Пробовал на css подобное, но что-то ни одно решение не подошло, а в свг я профан

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если бы Вы были профан в svg, то смогли бы сделать это задание.

Comment: @DogeDev не надо путать профана и профи

Comment: Градиент нужен? В вопросе про него не говорится, но на картинке он есть.

Comment: Да, получается всего 2 линии у меня, одна градиентом от голубого к синему, другая от желтого к оранжевому

Comment: Прогресс делается так - `stroke-dasharray: 314px` + `stroke-dashoffset: 314-(percent*314)/100 + 'px'`, где 314 это `диаметр*пи`. А вот с такой заливкой сложнее

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Такой вот костыльный вариант. Изменять stroke-dashoffset от 0 (полностью оранжевый круг) до 564 (полностью синий). Вариант с процентами я не осилил, может и можно так сделать.

[Код на codepen](https://codepen.io/Gortyser/pen/ZXMGrO)

```css
    .circle {
      cx: 60px;
      cy: 60px;
      r: 50px;
      fill: #fff;
      stroke: url(#linear-gradient);
      stroke-width: 4px;
    }

    .circle2 {
      cx: 61px;
      cy: 60px;
      r: 50px;
      fill: transparent;
      stroke: orange;
      stroke-width: 4px;
      stroke-dasharray: 564px;
      stroke-dashoffset: 450px;
      transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(-121px);
    }
```

```html
    <svg>
      <linearGradient id="linear-gradient">
        <stop offset="0%" stop-color="blue"/>
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="aliceblue"/>
      </linearGradient>
      <circle class="circle"></circle>
      <circle class="circle2"></circle>
    </svg>
```

Answer (score 6):

Возможно заинтересует такое решение...
есть такая библиотека  [D3JS (Data-Driven Documents)](https://d3js.org/)
она позволяет реализовывать красивые вещи, в том числе и вашу задачу
расширяя возможности SVG:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
  .percent-score {
    font: 10px sans-serif;
    line-height: 1;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 4em;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <svg width="900" height="500"></svg>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    // оределяем рабочую область и устанавливаем начало координат в ее центр
    var svg = d3.select("svg"),
      width = svg.attr("width"),
      height = svg.attr("height"),
      g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

    var radius = d3.min([width, height]) / 2;

    var arc = d3.arc()
      .innerRadius(radius - 120)
      .outerRadius(radius - 80)
      .startAngle(function(d) {
        return d;
      })
      .endAngle(function(d) {
        return d + dblpi / n * 1.2;
      });

    var percent = i = 0;
    var dblpi = 2 * Math.PI;
    var n = 300; //плавность цвета (разрешение)

    g.selectAll("path")
      .data(d3.range(0, dblpi, dblpi / n))
      .enter()
      .append("path")
      .attr("d", arc)
      .attr("id", "sector");

    g.append("text")
      .attr("class", "percent-score")
      .attr("dy", ".35em") // выравниваем текст по центру диаграммы
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .attr("id", "percent-text")
      .text(percent + "%");

    (function tick() {

      i = (i < n) ? i + 1 : 0;
      percent = (i / n * 100) | 0; // целое число %

      var color = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, i - 1, i, n])
        .range(["yellow", "orange", "blue", "lightblue"])
        .interpolate(d3.interpolateRgb)

      d3.select("#percent-text")
        .text(percent + "%");

      d3.selectAll("#sector")
        .style("fill", function(d, i) {
          return color(i);
        });
      setTimeout(tick, 30000 / n);
    })();
  </script>
```

и статический вариант:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
  .percent-score {
    font: 10px sans-serif;
    line-height: 1;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 4em;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <svg width="900" height="500"></svg>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    // оределяем рабочую область и устанавливаем начало координат в ее центр
    var svg = d3.select("svg"),
      width = svg.attr("width"),
      height = svg.attr("height"),
      g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

    var radius = d3.min([width, height]) / 2;

    var arc = d3.arc()
      .innerRadius(radius - 120)
      .outerRadius(radius - 80)
      .startAngle(function(d) {
        return d;
      })
      .endAngle(function(d) {
        return d + dblpi / n * 1.2;
      }); // 1.2 это чтоб артефакты на переходах перекрыть

    var n = 300; //плавность цвета (разрешение)
    var percent = 25; // процент жёлтооранжевого сектора

    var edge = n / 100 * percent;
    var dblpi = 2 * Math.PI;

    var color = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, edge - 1, edge, n])
      .range(["yellow", "orange", "blue", "lightblue"])
      .interpolate(d3.interpolateRgb)

    g.selectAll("path")
      .data(d3.range(0, dblpi, dblpi / n))
      .enter()
      .append("path")
      .attr("d", arc)
      .style("fill", function(d, i) {
        return color(i);
      });

    g.append("text")
      .attr("class", "percent-score")
      .attr("dy", ".35em") // выравниваем текст по центру диаграммы
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(percent + "%");
  </script>
```

а вот без D3 сложность с нелинейным градиентом
(вдоль окружности)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<svg width="270" height="270">
<defs>
<linearGradient id="hgrad" y2="100%" > 
    <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(0,255,255)" />
    <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(0,0,255)" />
</linearGradient>
<linearGradient id="lgrad" y1="100%" > 
    <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(245,0,0)" />
    <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,242,61)" />
    </linearGradient>    
</defs>

<g fill="none"> 
 <circle r="100" cx="135" cy="135" 
 stroke-width= "30"
 stroke-dasharray="471 157" 
 stroke="url(#hgrad)"/> <!-- 75%  2*Math.Pi*r*0,75 = 471 -->  

 <circle r="100" cx="135" cy="135" 
 transform="rotate(-90 135 135)"
 stroke-width= "30"
 stroke-dasharray="157 471" 
 stroke="url(#lgrad)"/> <!-- 25%  2*Math.Pi*r*0,25 = 157 -->  
</g>
</svg>
```

есть идеи?
хотя автору уже хватило и предыдущих 2-х ответов, хотя с градиентом явно вопрос не решён.

### Update 1:

Выше были примеры с постоянным размером секторов диаграммы  изменялся только их цвет и не всегда это хорошо, вот еще вариант с переменным размером секторов (их количество в этом примере одинаково, зависит от разрешения)
теперь по краям значений уменьшение размера секторов сохраняет плавность цвета и разрешение настраивается отдельно т.е. не зависит от количества данных
а саму модель круговой диаграммы теперь просчитывает D3 через генератор формы
круговой диаграммы Pie.

```html
-
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
  .percent-score {
    font: 10px sans-serif;
    line-height: 1;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 4em;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <svg width="900" height="500"></svg>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    // оределяем рабочую область и устанавливаем начало координат в ее центр
    var svg = d3.select("svg"),
      width = svg.attr("width"),
      height = svg.attr("height"),
      g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

    var radius = d3.min([width, height]) / 2;

    var percent, ticknum;
    var indata = 200; // шкала данных от 0 до indata
    var gradient = 50; //плавность цвета (разрешение)

    // вычисление цветов секторов в соответствии с разрешением
    var color = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, gradient - 1, gradient, 2 * gradient])
      .range(["yellow", "orange", "blue", "lightblue"])
      .interpolate(d3.interpolateRgb);

    // вычисление размеров секторов 
    var pie = d3.pie()
      .sort(null);

    var arc = d3.arc();

    // инициализация диаграммы и установка цветов секторам
    var path = g.datum(d3.range(gradient * 2)).selectAll("path")
      .data(pie)
      .enter()
      .append("path")
      .attr("d", arc.innerRadius(radius - 120).outerRadius(radius - 80))
      .style("fill", function(d, i) {
        return color(i);
      });

    g.append("text")
      .attr("class", "percent-score")
      .attr("dy", ".35em") // выравниваем текст по центру диаграммы
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .attr("id", "percent-text");

    (function tick() {

      ticknum = (ticknum < indata) ? ticknum + 1 : 0;
      percent = (ticknum / indata * 100) | 0; // получаем целое число %

      // определяем коэффициент для расчета размера сектора каждой из 2-х частей диаграммы
      // если текущий сектор меньше gradient то размер сектора увеличивается 
      // (это увеличивающаяся половина секторов диаграммы) иначе уменьшается  
      var sectorsize = d3.scaleThreshold()
        .domain([gradient])
        .range([ticknum / gradient, (indata - ticknum) / gradient]);
    // расчет модели диаграммы
      pie.value(function(d) {
        return sectorsize(d);
      }); 

      path.data(pie) // перерисовка секторов и поправка для конечной границы сектора - убираем артефакты
        .attr("d", arc.endAngle(function(d) {
          return d.endAngle + .01;
        }));

      d3.select("#percent-text")
        .text(percent + "%");

      setTimeout(tick, 30000 / indata);
    })();
  </script>
```

Кстати, подобный вопрос поднимался [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/642689)

Answer (score 2):

Если нужна статическая картинка, без динамической смени оранжевого круга, то я сделал бы вот так:

1.Рисуем 2 круга при помощи [circlarc.svg](https://eclipseeer.github.io/circlarc.svg/) -  сначала полный круг, потом маленькую часть.
 2. Добавляем каждому градиент (например [angryTools](http://angrytools.com/gradient/)).

> можно было легко менять от 0 до 100%

У меня ушло менее минуты.

```html
<svg fill="none" viewBox="0 0 1000 500"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <defs> 
    <linearGradient id="lgrad" x1="0%" y1="53%" x2="100%" y2="47%" > 
    <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,242,61);stop-opacity:1" />
    <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(245,0,0);stop-opacity:1" />
    </linearGradient> 
  </defs>
  <defs> 
    <linearGradient id="bluesky" x1="0%" y1="90%" x2="100%" y2="10%" > 
    <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(0,255,255);stop-opacity:1" />
    <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(0,0,255);stop-opacity:1" />
    </linearGradient> 
  </defs>
  
  <path d="M 454 75 C 509.23 75 554 119.77 554 175 L 554 175 C 554 230.23 509.23 275 454 275 L 454 275 C 398.77 275 354 230.23 354 175 L 354 175 C 354 119.77 398.77 75 454 75  L 454 95 C 409.82 95 374 130.82 374 175 L 374 175 C 374 219.18 409.82 255 454 255 L 454 255 C 498.18 255 534 219.18 534 175 L 534 175 C 534 130.82 498.18 95 454 95 Z" 
  fill="url(#bluesky)"/>
  <path d="M 454 75 C 509.23 75 554 119.77 554 175  L 534 175 C 534 130.82 498.18 95 454 95 Z" 
  fill="url(#lgrad)"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Обратите внимание на градиент, полагаю он должен быть вдоль по окружности

Comment: @eclipseeer , спасибо за ответ,  а через что вы рисовали свг ?

Comment: @YourDeveloper пару месяцев назад я сделал онлайн-рисовалку svg-кругов - [eclipseeer.github.io/circlarc.svg/](https://eclipseeer.github.io/circlarc.svg/). Вводишь начальный / конечный кути, радиус и получаешь готовый path

Comment: @eclipseeer Спасибо большое ! А можете что-нибудь подсказать по этому вопросу https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/732413/%D0%9F%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B3 ?