# Плавность заливки на svg

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, svg

Как реализовать плавную заливку `svg` при клике на кнопку.

Вот пример, справа квадрат для примера, так же хочу чтобы было с `svg`, но не знаю как это реализовать:

```js
$('.click-btn').click(function() {
  $('.for-example').toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
.s-tc-svg {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.example {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: green;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.for-example {
  position: absolute;
  top: -75px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 75px;
  background: yellow;
  transition: all 1.5s ease;
}

.for-example.active {
  top: 0px;
}

.click-btn {
  color: yelllow;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid brown;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="s-tc-svg">
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 21.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
  <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 238 158" style="enable-background:new 0 0 238 158;" xml:space="preserve">
    <style type="text/css">
      .st000{fill:#91979F;}
      .st111{font-family:'EtelkaProLight';}
      .st222{font-size:190px;}
      .st333{filter:url(#Adobe_OpacityMaskFilter);}
      .st444{mask:url(#SVGID_1_);}
      .st555{fill:#C1C5CB;}
    </style>
    <g>
      <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1 145)" class="st000 st111 st222">60</text>
    </g>
    <defs>
      <filter id="Adobe_OpacityMaskFilter" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="1" y="-16.2" width="236.2" height="210.5">
        <feFlood  style="flood-color:white;flood-opacity:1" result="back"/>
        <feBlend  in="SourceGraphic" in2="back" mode="normal"/>
      </filter>
    </defs>
    <mask maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="1" y="-16.2" width="236.2" height="210.5" id="SVGID_1_">
      <g class="st333">
        <polygon points="32,153 218,-11 267,-9 246,173 113,210 22,158   "/>
      </g>
    </mask>
    <g class="st444">
      <g>
        <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1 145)" class="st555 st111 st222">60</text>
      </g>
    </g>
  </svg>

</div>

<div class="example">
  <div class="for-example"></div>
</div>
<span class="click-btn">Нажми на меня</span>
```

Пробовал разбить `svg` на 2 части и поиграться с `overflow: hidden;` и позиционированием, но толку мало:

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 131px;
  width: 186px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.svg-1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: -17px;
  width: 238px;
  height: 158px;
  z-index: 1;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.svg-2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: -17px;
  width: 238px;
  height: 158px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="svg-1">
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 21.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
    <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 238 158" style="enable-background:new 0 0 238 158;" xml:space="preserve">
    <style type="text/css">
     .st000{fill:#91979F;}
     .st111{font-family:'EtelkaProLight';}
     .st222{font-size:190px;}
     .st333{filter:url(#Adobe_OpacityMaskFilter);}
     .st444{mask:url(#SVGID_1_);}
     .st555{fill:#C1C5CB;}
    </style>
    <defs>
     <filter id="Adobe_OpacityMaskFilter" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="1" y="-16.2" width="236.2" height="210.5">
      <feFlood  style="flood-color:white;flood-opacity:1" result="back"/>
      <feBlend  in="SourceGraphic" in2="back" mode="normal"/>
     </filter>
    </defs>
    <mask maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="1" y="-16.2" width="236.2" height="210.5" id="SVGID_1_">
     <g class="st333">
      <polygon points="32,153 218,-11 267,-9 246,173 113,210 22,158   "/>
     </g>
    </mask>
    <g class="st444">
     <g>
      <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1 145)" class="st555 st111 st222">60</text>
     </g>
    </g>
    </svg>

  </div>

  <div class="svg-2">

    <div class="s-tc-svg">
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 21.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
      <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 238 158" style="enable-background:new 0 0 238 158;" xml:space="preserve">
    <style type="text/css">
     .st00{fill:#91979F;}
     .st11{font-family:'EtelkaProLight';}
     .st22{font-size:190px;}
     .st33{filter:url(#Adobe_OpacityMaskFilter);}
     .st44{mask:url(#SVGID_1_);}
     .st55{fill:#C1C5CB;}
    </style>
    <g>
     <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1 145)" class="st000 st111 st222">60</text>
    </g>
    <defs>
     <filter id="Adobe_OpacityMaskFilter" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="1" y="-16.2" width="236.2" height="210.5">
      <feFlood  style="flood-color:white;flood-opacity:1" result="back"/>
      <feBlend  in="SourceGraphic" in2="back" mode="normal"/>
     </filter>
    </defs>
    <mask maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="1" y="-16.2" width="236.2" height="210.5" id="SVGID_1_">
     <g class="st333">
      <polygon points="32,153 218,-11 267,-9 246,173 113,210 22,158   "/>
     </g>
    </mask>
    </svg>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С помощью различных сайтов и помощи на них, пришел вот к чему.

```js
$('.click').click(function() {
 $('.st333').css('transform', 'translateX(0px)');
});
```

```css
.st333 {
  transition: all 2s ease;
  filter: url(#Adobe_OpacityMaskFilter);
  transform: translateX(-140px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 21.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
    <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
      viewBox="0 0 238 158" style="enable-background:new 0 0 238 158;" xml:space="preserve">
    <style type="text/css">
     .st000{fill:#91979F;}
     .st111{font-family:'EtelkaProLight';}
     .st222{font-size:190px;}
     
     .st444  {
            mask:url(#SVGID_1_);
         }
     .st555{fill:#C1C5CB;}
    </style>
    <g>
     <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1 145)" class="st000 st111 st222">60</text>
    </g>
    <defs>
     <filter id="Adobe_OpacityMaskFilter" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="1" y="-16.2" width="236.2" height="210.5">
      <feFlood  style="flood-color:white;flood-opacity:1" result="back"/>
      <feBlend  in="SourceGraphic" in2="back" mode="normal"/>
     </filter>
    </defs>
    <mask maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="1" y="-16.2" width="236.2" height="210.5" id="SVGID_1_">
     <g class="st333">
      <polygon points="32,153 218,-11 267,-9 246,173 113,210 22,158   "/>
     </g>
    </mask>
    <g class="st444">
     <g>
      <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1 145)" class="st555 st111 st222">60</text>
     </g>
    </g>
    </svg>
       <span class="click">Нажми</span>
```